# Searching through directories for files containing a word or words in a list

Tags: python

I want a program - search(file, list), to search say USB stick D for texts that contain a word or words from a list, if it contains a word, it would put it in a list and move on to the next word. For each document it find words in, I want it to print a statement where it says 'word[0], word[1], word[2] in "this file directory" Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import os

def search(file, list):
    if list == []:
        return
    else:
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            try:
                infile = open(file, 'r')
                doc = infile.read()
            except:
                return
            infile.close()
            print ('Searching {}'.format(file))
            if list[0] in doc:
                print('{} in {}'.format(list[0], file))
        elif os.path.isdir(file):
            for item in os.listdir(file):
                itempath = os.path.join(file, item)
                search(itempath, list)
    return search(file, list[1:])
```

Comment: For starters, You forgot to return in the recursive call `return search(itempath, list)`

Comment: Thanks, I got it to run through the list now, but I forgot an additional step in the prompt, updating the question now

Comment: If you want to look over the words one by one, wouldn't it make sense to just iterate over the list instead of returning 'return search(file, list[1:])'?

Comment: There are certain restrictions the professor placed on our problems. We can't use techniques we haven't discussed in class.

Answer (score 0):

You're not iterating over your `list` (btw. do not use `file` and `list` as variable names, you're shadowing the built-in types) to check for the terms, you'd have to do something like:

```
found_words = []
for word in list:
    if word in doc:
        found_words.append(word)
if found_words:
    print('{} in {}'.format(", ".join(found_words), file))
```

instead if you want to check for all the terms. However, you're making this far more complex than it needs to be. For starters, you should use `os.walk()` to go through all your subdirectories recursively. Second, reading your whole file in memory is not a good idea - not only that the search will be slower on average, but the moment you encounter a big file you might start having memory issues...

I'd do it like this:

```
def search(path, terms):
    result = {}  # store our result in the form "file_path": [found terms]
    start_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(path))  # full path, resolving a symlink
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_path):  # recurse our selected dir
        for source in files:  # loop through each files
            source_path = os.path.join(root, source)  # full path to our file
            try:
                with open(source_path, "r") as f:  # open our current file
                    found_terms = []  # store for our potentially found terms
                    for line in f:  # loop through it line-by line
                        for term in terms:  # go through all our terms and check for a match
                            if term in line:  # if the current term exists on the line
                                found_terms.append(term)  # add the found term to our store
                    if found_terms:  # if we found any of the terms...
                        result[source_path] = found_terms  # store it in our result
            except IOError:
                pass  # ignore I/O errors, we may optionally store list of failed files...
    return result
```

It would return a dictionary whose keys are set to your file path, and values are the discovered terms. So, for example, if you were to search the files in the current folder (running folder for the script) for the word "import" you could do it with:

```
search_results = search("./", ["import, export"])
for key in search_results:
    print("{} in {}".format(", ".join(search_results[key]), key)
```

and it should print you your desired result. It could also use a check for file extension/type so you don't waste your time trying to go through an unreadable/binary file. Also, codec checkup should be in order as, in dependence of your file, reading its lines might raise an unicode error (default for decoding). Bottom line, there's a lot of room for improvement...

Also, note that you're not precisely looking for a word, but just mere existence of the passed characters sequence. For example, if you were to search for `cat` it would return files containing `caterpillar` too. And, also, there are dedicated tools that will do this in just a fraction of the time.